# Account Sharing Rules set up different than other standard objects

Tags: force.com, security

I'm setting up sharing rules for the account object, and I see that there are extra permissions for Accounts that don't appear on other standard objects. you get to define the level of access for these  objects. What's special about them, and not Campaign or Lead (for example)

- Default Account, Contract and Asset
- Contact
- Opportunity
- Case

FWIW the org wide default access for these standard objects are private

- Lead
- Account, Contract and Asset
- Contact
- Opportunity
- Case
- Campaign

Comment: Contacts and Opportunities have a special (Master-Detail like) relationship with Account, hence why these additional attributes on Account sharing rules, as it would probably make sense for someone for example to expose (or not) Opportunities to those who can see related Accounts.

Comment: @techtrekker You should probably post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contacts and Opportunities have a special (Master-Detail like) relationship with Account, hence why these additional attributes on Account sharing rules, as it would probably make sense for someone for example to expose (or not) Opportunities to those who can see related Accounts.

Leads and Campaigns are fairly 'solitary' in that you wouldn't normally control the visibility of other objects based on the visibility of the Lead Record.

Also in the CRM context, (for sales) you'd probably want to control based on the Account visibility, whether people should be able to see (or not) related Contacts and Opportunities, etc and (for service) control whether related cases are visible.

Comment: you mean, contacts and opps have  polymorphic relationships with acct?

Comment: Not polymorphic, Tasks have polymorphic relationships, eg WhoId can point to a Contact, Lead, etc. Accounts-Contact and Account-Opportunity is Master-Detail 'like', but not quite.